# WxWidgets Build on OSX 10.15.4 Error ( Try a different SDK )

Tags: macos, wxwidgets, macos-catalina

I have downloaded wxWidgets-3.0.5
onto my macbook pro running osx 10.15.4

i followed directions here and am stuck at one of first steps
on page: https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/plat_osx_install.html

```
mkdir build-cocoa-debug
cd build-cocoa-debug
**../configure --enable-debug**
make
```

The ..configure step is asking me to **"Try a different SDK"** 
I do not understand what I need to do.

here is the terminal session:

```
Marks-MBP-2:build-cocoa-debug markwardell$ ../configure --enable-debug
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin19.4.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin19.4.0
checking for --disable-gui... no
checking for --enable-monolithic... no
checking for --enable-plugins... no
checking for --without-subdirs... no
checking for --enable-official_build... no
checking for --disable-all-features... no
checking for --enable-universal... no
checking for --enable-nanox... no
checking for --enable-gpe... no
checking for toolkit... osx_cocoa
checking for --with-libpng... yes
checking for --with-libjpeg... yes
checking for --with-libtiff... yes
checking for --without-libjbig... no
checking for --without-liblzma... no
checking for --with-libxpm... yes
checking for --with-libiconv... yes
checking for --with-libmspack... no
checking for --without-gtkprint... no
checking for --with-gnomevfs... no
checking for --with-libnotify... yes
checking for --with-hildon... no
checking for --with-opengl... auto
checking for --with-dmalloc... no
checking for --with-sdl... no
checking for --with-regex... yes
checking for --with-zlib... yes
checking for --with-expat... yes
checking for --with-macosx-sdk... 
checking for --with-macosx-version-min... 
checking for --enable-debug... yes
checking for --disable-debug_flag... no
checking for --enable-debug_info... yes
checking for --enable-debug_gdb... no
checking for --enable-debug_cntxt... no
checking for --enable-mem_tracing... no
checking for --disable-shared... no
checking for --enable-stl... no
checking for --enable-std_containers... no
checking for --enable-std_iostreams... yes
checking for --enable-std_string... yes
checking for --enable-std_string_conv_in_wxstring... no
checking for --disable-unicode... no
checking for --enable-mslu... no
checking for --enable-utf8... no
checking for --enable-utf8only... no
checking for --enable-extended_rtti... no
checking for --disable-optimise... yes
checking for --enable-profile... no
checking for --enable-no_rtti... no
checking for --enable-no_exceptions... no
checking for --enable-permissive... no
checking for --enable-no_deps... no
checking for --disable-vararg_macros... no
checking for --enable-universal_binary... no
checking for --enable-macosx_arch... no
checking for --enable-compat26... no
checking for --disable-compat28... no
checking for --disable-rpath... no
checking for --enable-objc_uniquifying... no
checking for --disable-visibility... no
checking for --disable-tls... no
checking for --enable-intl... yes
checking for --enable-xlocale... yes
checking for --enable-config... yes
checking for --enable-protocols... yes
checking for --enable-ftp... yes
checking for --enable-http... yes
checking for --enable-fileproto... yes
checking for --enable-sockets... yes
checking for --enable-ipv6... no
checking for --enable-ole... yes
checking for --enable-dataobj... yes
checking for --enable-ipc... yes
checking for --enable-baseevtloop... yes
checking for --enable-epollloop... yes
checking for --enable-selectloop... yes
checking for --enable-any... yes
checking for --enable-apple_ieee... yes
checking for --enable-arcstream... yes
checking for --enable-base64... yes
checking for --enable-backtrace... yes
checking for --enable-catch_segvs... yes
checking for --enable-cmdline... yes
checking for --enable-datetime... yes
checking for --enable-debugreport... yes
checking for --enable-dialupman... yes
checking for --enable-dynlib... yes
checking for --enable-dynamicloader... yes
checking for --enable-exceptions... yes
checking for --enable-ffile... yes
checking for --enable-file... yes
checking for --enable-filehistory... yes
checking for --enable-filesystem... yes
checking for --enable-fontenum... yes
checking for --enable-fontmap... yes
checking for --enable-fs_archive... yes
checking for --enable-fs_inet... yes
checking for --enable-fs_zip... yes
checking for --enable-fsvolume... yes
checking for --enable-fswatcher... yes
checking for --enable-geometry... yes
checking for --enable-log... yes
checking for --enable-longlong... yes
checking for --enable-mimetype... yes
checking for --enable-printfposparam... yes
checking for --enable-snglinst... yes
checking for --enable-sound... yes
checking for --enable-stdpaths... yes
checking for --enable-stopwatch... yes
checking for --enable-streams... yes
checking for --enable-sysoptions... yes
checking for --enable-tarstream... yes
checking for --enable-textbuf... yes
checking for --enable-textfile... yes
checking for --enable-timer... yes
checking for --enable-variant... yes
checking for --enable-zipstream... yes
checking for --enable-url... yes
checking for --enable-protocol... yes
checking for --enable-protocol_http... yes
checking for --enable-protocol_ftp... yes
checking for --enable-protocol_file... yes
checking for --enable-threads... yes
checking for --enable-iniconf... no
checking for --enable-regkey... yes
checking for --enable-docview... yes
checking for --enable-help... yes
checking for --enable-mshtmlhelp... yes
checking for --enable-html... yes
checking for --enable-htmlhelp... yes
checking for --enable-xrc... yes
checking for --enable-aui... yes
checking for --enable-propgrid... yes
checking for --enable-ribbon... yes
checking for --enable-stc... yes
checking for --enable-constraints... yes
checking for --enable-loggui... yes
checking for --enable-logwin... yes
checking for --enable-logdialog... yes
checking for --enable-mdi... yes
checking for --enable-mdidoc... yes
checking for --enable-mediactrl... auto
checking for --enable-gstreamer8... no
checking for --enable-richtext... yes
checking for --enable-postscript... yes
checking for --enable-printarch... yes
checking for --enable-svg... yes
checking for --enable-webkit... yes
checking for --enable-webview... yes
checking for --disable-qtkit... no
checking for --enable-clipboard... yes
checking for --enable-dnd... yes
checking for --disable-controls... no
checking for --enable-markup... yes
checking for --enable-accel... yes
checking for --enable-animatectrl... yes
checking for --enable-bannerwindow... yes
checking for --enable-artstd... yes
checking for --enable-arttango... auto
checking for --enable-bmpbutton... yes
checking for --enable-bmpcombobox... yes
checking for --enable-button... yes
checking for --enable-calendar... yes
checking for --enable-caret... yes
checking for --enable-checkbox... yes
checking for --enable-checklst... yes
checking for --enable-choice... yes
checking for --enable-choicebook... yes
checking for --enable-collpane... yes
checking for --enable-colourpicker... yes
checking for --enable-combobox... yes
checking for --enable-comboctrl... yes
checking for --enable-commandlinkbutton... yes
checking for --enable-dataviewctrl... yes
checking for --enable-datepick... yes
checking for --enable-detect_sm... yes
checking for --enable-dirpicker... yes
checking for --enable-display... yes
checking for --enable-editablebox... yes
checking for --enable-filectrl... yes
checking for --enable-filepicker... yes
checking for --enable-fontpicker... yes
checking for --enable-gauge... yes
checking for --enable-grid... yes
checking for --enable-headerctrl... yes
checking for --enable-hyperlink... yes
checking for --enable-imaglist... yes
checking for --enable-infobar... yes
checking for --enable-listbook... yes
checking for --enable-listbox... yes
checking for --enable-listctrl... yes
checking for --enable-notebook... yes
checking for --enable-notifmsg... yes
checking for --enable-odcombobox... yes
checking for --enable-popupwin... yes
checking for --enable-prefseditor... yes
checking for --enable-radiobox... yes
checking for --enable-radiobtn... yes
checking for --enable-richmsgdlg... yes
checking for --enable-richtooltip... yes
checking for --enable-rearrangectrl... yes
checking for --enable-sash... yes
checking for --enable-scrollbar... yes
checking for --enable-searchctrl... yes
checking for --enable-slider... yes
checking for --enable-spinbtn... yes
checking for --enable-spinctrl... yes
checking for --enable-splitter... yes
checking for --enable-statbmp... yes
checking for --enable-statbox... yes
checking for --enable-statline... yes
checking for --enable-stattext... yes
checking for --enable-statusbar... yes
checking for --enable-taskbaricon... yes
checking for --enable-tbarnative... yes
checking for --enable-textctrl... yes
checking for --enable-timepick... yes
checking for --enable-tipwindow... yes
checking for --enable-togglebtn... yes
checking for --enable-toolbar... yes
checking for --enable-toolbook... yes
checking for --enable-treebook... yes
checking for --enable-treectrl... yes
checking for --enable-treelist... yes
checking for --enable-commondlg... yes
checking for --enable-aboutdlg... yes
checking for --enable-choicedlg... yes
checking for --enable-coldlg... yes
checking for --enable-filedlg... yes
checking for --enable-finddlg... yes
checking for --enable-fontdlg... yes
checking for --enable-dirdlg... yes
checking for --enable-msgdlg... yes
checking for --enable-numberdlg... yes
checking for --enable-splash... yes
checking for --enable-textdlg... yes
checking for --enable-tipdlg... yes
checking for --enable-progressdlg... yes
checking for --enable-wizarddlg... yes
checking for --enable-menus... yes
checking for --enable-miniframe... yes
checking for --enable-tooltips... yes
checking for --enable-splines... yes
checking for --enable-mousewheel... yes
checking for --enable-validators... yes
checking for --enable-busyinfo... yes
checking for --enable-hotkey... auto
checking for --enable-joystick... yes
checking for --enable-metafile... auto
checking for --enable-dragimage... yes
checking for --enable-accessibility... no
checking for --enable-uiactionsim... yes
checking for --enable-dctransform... yes
checking for --enable-webviewwebkit... yes
checking for --enable-palette... yes
checking for --enable-image... yes
checking for --enable-gif... yes
checking for --enable-pcx... yes
checking for --enable-tga... yes
checking for --enable-iff... yes
checking for --enable-pnm... yes
checking for --enable-xpm... yes
checking for --enable-ico_cur... yes
checking for --enable-dccache... yes
checking for --enable-ps-in-msw... yes
checking for --enable-ownerdrawn... yes
checking for --enable-uxtheme... yes
checking for --enable-wxdib... yes
checking for --enable-webviewie... yes
checking for --enable-autoidman... no
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether we are using the Intel C compiler... no
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking whether gcc needs -traditional... no
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking whether we are using the Intel C++ compiler... no
checking whether we are using the IBM xlC C++ compiler... no
checking for ar... ar
checking if C compiler (gcc -mmacosx-version-min=10.5) works with SDK/version options... yes
checking if C++ compiler (g++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.5) works with SDK/version options... configure: error: in `/Users/markwardell/src/bitbucket/wxWidgets-3.0.5/build-cocoa-debug':
configure: error: no.  Try a different SDK
```

HERE IS THE CONFIG.LOG

```
The error undefined identifier 'choke'
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
....
......
........

configure: exit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check `config.log` file to see which error exactly you're getting, but in any case you're *strongly* recommended to use 3.1.3 with 10.15 as 3.0 was released many versions before it and so can't, and doesn't support many of its features.

Comment: Hello VZ. 1) config.log is attached. FYI that is what I am asking help with. 2) 3.05 is the latest stable release as per doc page https://www.wxwidgets.org/downloads/

Comment: and here are the relevant lines from above: checking: if C compiler (gcc -mmacosx-version-min=10.5) works with SDK/version options... yes
checking if C++ compiler (g++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.5) works with SDK/version options... configure: error: in `/Users/markwardell/src/bitbucket/wxWidgets-3.0.5/build-cocoa-debug':
configure: error: no.  Try a different SDK

Comment: config.log was too long to attach 'choke' identifier is the issue

Comment: @MarkWardell, as Vadim pointed out you should start with 3.1.3. While 3.0.5 `IS` stable version and was recently released, it still doesn't contain many things that OSX 10.15 has.

Comment: The Website is quite clear that 3.0.5 is the stable version

Comment: There is not enough context in the part of `config.log` you show, you should really look at what exactly triggers the message about the compiler not working, we can't help you without this information.

Comment: Re: stable/development debate, as explained in 3.1.3 [release announcement](http://wxwidgets.org/news/2019/10/wxwidgets-3.1.3-released/), it's only "development" because it's not API-compatible with 3.0. If you're starting developing with wxWidgets, this doesn't really matter to you.

Answer (score 0):

To acquire and build on Mac do not follow the instructions on website. or download from the many sites and locations. here is how you need to git:

//Acquire
git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets.git

//Build
mkdir build-cocoa-debug
cd build-cocoa-debug
../configure --enable-debug
make

I am disappointed with the website in that it has an older version marked as the stable release - It can be a real time waster. Yet that version did not build.

Get it together WXWidgets!